# Why can't region test the range of points?

Tags: c#

```
RectangleF rectF = new RectangleF(-10,10,20,20);
Region region = new Region(rectF);

PointF pp = new PointF(0,0);
bool IsResult = region.IsVisible(pp);
```

why the variable IsResult is equal false?
rect range include the point, why the variable return false?

A square with length and width of 20, top left corner is -10, 10, center is not 0, 0? Why not include 0, 0 point?

Answer (score 3):

> rect range include the point - It's not
>
> RectangleF rectF = new RectangleF(-10,10,20,20);

This rectangle left corner in x=-10, y=10.Then width=20, height=20.
Point at 0,0 isn't in this rectangle.

Comment: A square with length and width of 20, top left corner is - 10, 10, center is not 0, 0? Why not include 0, 0 pont?

Comment: @xuyunhai because 0(Y) is less than rect's Y(10)

Comment: @xuyunhai, maybe you wanted -10,-10 as start? Then 0,0 would in fact be the center

Answer (score 2):

The coordinate system is slightly confusing in WinForms. The 0,0 is in top-left corner with X axis going left and Y axis going down. This is how your rectangle looks like.

As you can see, 0,0 is not inside the rectangle defined by `new RectangleF(-10,10,20,20)`.

[image]

Comment: you mean is that x axis to the right is a positive direction, y axis to the bottom is a positive direction?

Comment: @xuyunhai yes. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-types-of-coordinate-systems-about